# Give a combinatorial proof of the following identity: $n^3 = n(n - 1)(n - 2) + 3n(n - 1) + n$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

> Give a combinatorial proof of the following identity: Let $n$ be a positive integer. $n^3 = n(n - 1)(n - 2) + 3n(n - 1) + n$.

How would I go about proving this identity combinatorially?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$n^3$ is the number of possible triplets of numbers from $1$ to $n$.
$n(n-1)(n-2)$ is the number of triplets where no $2$ numbers are the same. Then, $n(n-1)$ is the number of triplets with $(a, a, b)$ ($a\not =b$), so $3n(n-1)$ is the number of triplets with exactly two equal elements. $n$ is the number of triplets with all elements the same.

Comment: I would assume that the second sentence needs some editing.

Comment: Thank you, this helps tremendously. But how did you determine that $3n(n-1)$ is the set of all lists with exactly two equal elements?

Comment: Because, either first equals the second, or second equals the third or third equals the first.

Comment: "that 3n(n−1) is the set of all lists with exactly two equal elements?"  Because there are $n(n-1)$ ways you can pick which two elements, and there are $3$ ways you can arrange the two like elements and the one unlike element.

Answer (score 4):

Consider an $n\times n\times n$ cube.  We partition it into five pieces:

First, there is a large $n\times (n-1)\times (n-2)$ block.  This leaves an L-shaped piece, of height $n$, with one arm width $1$ and the other arm of width $2$.  We partition the arms into three slabs, each of size $n\times 1\times (n-1)$.  This leaves the corner of the L, which is a single $n\times 1\times 1$ long piece.

MS Paint masterpiece below: 
 [image]

Comment: How is it combinatorial?

Comment: We are double-counting the same object.  If you like, take the cube as a collection of $n^3$ small cubes, and we are counting the number of those small cubes.

Comment: Ok, fair enough